# How can I add picture to notification large icon with Picasso having only URL of this picture?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, picasso, android-bitmap

How can I set Large Icon to notification? I getting URL of the Image in timetable.getImage(). In my project, Picasso supports get() method, not with().
I am new in android, please help. 
You can see my notififcation on picture below. Icon image of notification is hardcoded. But I need this icon image from timetable.getImage(). 
This is my code:

public class EpisodeNotifyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ativity_episode_notify);


    final Timetable timetable = (Timetable) requestService.getResult();
    ImageView serImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.seriesImage1);

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.notify);
    Picasso.get()
            .load(timetable.getImage())
            .into(serImage);    

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendNotification(timetable.getSeriesName().toUpperCase() + ", New Episode", timetable.getEpisodesSeason().toString() + "x" + timetable.getEpisodesNumber() + " " + timetable.getEpisodeName());
                      }        });    }  

private void sendNotification(String messageTitle, String messageBody) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EpisodeNotifyActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("my_notification", "n_channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);
        notificationChannel.setDescription("description");
        notificationChannel.setName("Channel Name");
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_live_tv_black_24dp)
                .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
             //   .setLargeIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setChannelId("my_notification")
                .setColor(Color.parseColor("#3F5996"));
        assert notificationManager != null;
        int m = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        notificationManager.notify(m, notificationBuilder.build());
    }    
}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class EpisodeNotifyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ativity_episode_notify);


    final Timetable timetable = (Timetable) requestService.getResult();
    ImageView serImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.seriesImage1);

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.notify);
    Picasso.get()
            .load(timetable.getImage())
            .into(serImage);


    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EpisodeNotifyActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("my_notification", "n_channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);
        notificationChannel.setDescription("description");
        notificationChannel.setName("Channel Name");
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        final NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_live_tv_black_24dp)
                .setContentTitle(timetable.getSeriesName().toUpperCase() + ", New Episode")
                .setContentText(timetable.getEpisodesSeason().toString() + "x" + timetable.getEpisodesNumber() + " " + timetable.getEpisodeName())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setChannelId("my_notification")
                .setColor(Color.parseColor("#3F5996"));


        Picasso.get().load(timetable.getImage())
                .into(new Target() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

                        // !!!!!!!!  MAGIC HAPPENS HERE
                        notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(bitmap);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                    }
                });


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendNotification();
            }
        });

    }
}

private void sendNotification() {
    assert notificationManager != null;
    int m = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    notificationManager.notify(m, notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

Comment: No, I need to load it into Notification with method set.largeIcon().  And I don't know how to get bitmap from Picasso, cause set.largeIcon() needs bitmap

Comment: My answer does that. If you look into the code `notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(bitmap);` in the `onBitmapLoaded()` method in the Picasso code. Actually I made this code to match exactly what you want. You can even copy/paste the entire class EpisodeNotifyActivity and it should work. What you want to achieve (image from Internet into the notification with Picasso) I tested successfully than I change the code to match yours.

Comment: Did you even scroll down my answer?

Comment: Oh, sorry, now I see. Yes, previous time i saw you answer from my phone and didn't see everything. Thank you!